# How can we set life time of a Micro-service?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, autoscaling, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a scenario where I need to deploy the same service on multiple server/instances (scaling), is there any configuration property(application.properties) available in Spring Boot(Restful Micro Service),which says, after some period of time those new services should automatically stop working(shutdown).

**For example:**

Assume, in festive season, e-commerce website getting orders in high volume. So they decided to add few more instances of an Order Process service. So manually they started those instances. After 5 days, all those new instances have to die on their own, instead of again a manual intervention to stop them.

I guess there should be some property, which triggers to kill(self distruction) the service on its own.

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1, Eureka as Service registry, Zuul for API Gateway/Router.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task

Comment: Update question with information about runtime environment - is it a cloud? AWS, CF? Do u use anything like Elastic Beanstalk, Kubernetes, etc.?

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to reconsider your infrastructure and go with Docker and Kubernetes route, this is an ideal use case for [kubernetes autoscale](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/07/autoscaling-in-kubernetes.html)